# Is there a way to give a pie chart in chart.js a different color outer border than the border color between segments?

Tags: canvas, chart.js

I'm using chart.js to draw some pie charts on a webpage I'm building. I want the pies to look like this normally, with [a visible border around the pie and between segments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtaKm.png).

But occasionally, the underlying data throws datapoints with zero values into the mix, meaning the chart looks like this [circle with a single line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPpio.png).

Whilst I can turn off the borderWidth property when there are datapoints that are zero values, that turns off the property for the whole pie, [meaning they look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miP57.png).

So, is there some way to make it so that when there is only one datapoint with actual data, there is still a border around the pie itself?

Or perhaps a way where whenever there is only one datapoint with actual data, to set the border width property to 0 and then draw a circle onto of the pie in the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom inline plugin for this in combination with a scriptable option for the `borderWidth` itself.

Plugin:

```js
{
    id: 'circleAroundPieDoughnut',
    beforeDatasetsDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
      if (chart.data.datasets[0].data.length > 1) return;

      const {
        ctx,
        canvas
      } = chart;
      const {
        top,
        left,
        width,
        height
      } = chart.chartArea;
      const x = left + width / 2;
      const y = top + height / 2;
      const outerRadius = chart._metasets[0].data[0].outerRadius;

      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.arc(x, y, outerRadius + ((options.width || 0) / 2), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.lineWidth = options.width || 1
      ctx.strokeStyle = options.color || '#000';
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
```

Live Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12],
      borderWidth: (ctx) => (ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data.length === 1 ? 0 : 3),
      backgroundColor: ["Red"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    radius: '98%',
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      circleAroundPieDoughnut: {
        width: 6, // Width of the border, defaults to 1
        color: 'blue' // Color of the border, defaults to black
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'circleAroundPieDoughnut',
    beforeDatasetsDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
      if (chart.data.datasets[0].data.length > 1) return;

      const {
        ctx,
        canvas
      } = chart;
      const {
        top,
        left,
        width,
        height
      } = chart.chartArea;
      const x = left + width / 2;
      const y = top + height / 2;
      const outerRadius = chart._metasets[0].data[0].outerRadius;

      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.arc(x, y, outerRadius + ((options.width || 0) / 2), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.lineWidth = options.width || 1
      ctx.strokeStyle = options.color || '#000';
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/us52em7f/18/

Comment: Can you see my post below - it _almost_ works, but seems to have a small bug.

Comment: You can set the `radius` property in the options to for example 98%, need to check what works for you, see updated answer for result. Radius option explained: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/charts/doughnut.html#config-options

Comment: Thanks - that fixed things!

Answer (score 0):

That's brilliant - I've implemented this, but seem to be getting a slightly boxy circle that extends beyond the bounds of the canvas in circumstances where the function draws the border where there's only one datapoint. Any ideas on how to fix?

[image]

```
    function makepie(a,b,c,d){
 if (b <= 0) {n = 'n'} else {n = 'y'}
  if (c <= 0) {o = 'n'} else {o = 'y'}
  if (d <= 0) {p = 'n'} else {p = 'y'}
  q = n + o + p
  if (q == 'nnn') {s = [a];r = ['Indianred'];u = ['Emails']}
  if (q == 'yyy') {s = [a, b, c, d];r = ['Indianred', 'salmon', 'pink', 'mistyrose'];u = ['Emails','Calls','Meetings','Working']}
  if (q == 'ynn') {s = [a, b];r = ['Indianred', 'salmon'];u = ['Emails','Calls']}
  if (q == 'nyn') {s = [a, c];r = ['Indianred', 'pink', ];u = ['Emails','Working']}
  if (q == 'nny') {s = [a, d];r = ['Indianred', 'mistyrose'];u = ['Emails','Working']}
  if (q == 'yyn') {s = [a, b, c];r = ['Indianred', 'salmon', 'pink'];u = ['Emails','Calls','Meetings']}
  if (q == 'yny') {s = [a, b, d];r = ['Indianred', 'salmon', 'mistyrose'];u = ['Emails','Calls','Working']}
  if (q == 'nyy') {s = [a, c, d];r = ['Indianred', 'pink', 'mistyrose'];u = ['Emails','Meetings','Working']}
  var options = {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
      labels: u,
      datasets: [{
        data: s,
        borderColor: '#6f6f6f',
        borderWidth: (ctx) => (ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data.length === 1 ? 0 : 3),
        backgroundColor: r
      }]
    },
    options: {
        hover: {mode: null},
        animation: {duration: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 20) * 100},
        legend: {display: false,labels: {display: false}},
        rotation: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)+1),
        tooltips: {enabled: false},
        plugins: {
        legend: {display: false},
        circleAroundPieDoughnut: {
          width: 3,
          color: '#6f6f6f'
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: [{
      id: 'circleAroundPieDoughnut',
      beforeDatasetsDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
        if (chart.data.datasets[0].data.length > 1) return;

        var {
          ctx,
          canvas
        } = chart;
        var {
          top,
          left,
          width,
          height
        } = chart.chartArea;
        var x = left + width / 2;
        var y = top + height / 2;
        var outerRadius = chart._metasets[0].data[0].outerRadius;

        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(x, y, outerRadius + ((options.width || 0) / 2), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.lineWidth = options.width || 1
        ctx.strokeStyle = options.color || '#000';
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    }],

  }

  var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
  new Chart(ctx, options);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/theboyler/mp016df2/17/